# CSS: How can i show my divs in block?

Tags: html, css

and i need to position my div in block , or whatever it names, so that when a lot of text is entered maintains its position and is not shown below, i attached some screenshots of what I want to do

[image: This is i want to do] 
[image: :(]

EDIT: sorry i forget post my code :/

**CSS:**

```
 .columnas{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.full{
    width:98%;
    margin: 20px 1%;
    background: #212121;
    height: 40px;
}
.col-3{
    width: 34%;
    margin: 5px 1%;
    background: #3b5998;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    @media screen and (max-width: $tablet){
    width: 47.86%;  
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: $mobile){
    width: 98%; 
    }
}
.col-4{
    width: 26%;
    margin: 5px 1%;
    background: #ffff00;
    display: inline-block;
    //height: 40px;
    float: left;
}
.col-7{
    width: 70%;
    margin: 5px 1%;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    //height: 40px;
    float: left;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="sass/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <title>Frontend</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="columnas">
            <div class="full"></div>
            <div class="col-7"><p>Text1</p></div>
            <div class="col-4"><p>Text2</p></div>
            <div class="col-3"><p>Text3</p></div>
            <div class="col-3"><p>Text4</p></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please post your code in the question so we can help you.

Comment: Methinks you need to be a bit clearer about what you're looking for.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: sorry i posted my code now

Comment: Link please. I'll inspect

Comment: Please provide a link so I can inspect, and better yet, a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the [overflow property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) :
try adding this css property to your div :

`overflow: scroll;`

Comment: No i don't need a scroll, i just need that my divs stay in their positions even i insert a long text and it don't shown below like the second picture's blue columns

Answer (score 0):

You need add to your div style:

```
 div {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: I tried that and don't works :( or something in my code is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 <div class="columnas">
    <div class="full"></div>
    <div class="col-7"><p>Text1</p></div>
    <div class="col-3"><p>Text3</p></div>
    <div class="col-3"><p>Text4</p></div>
    <div class="col-4"><p>Text2</p></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.columnas{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.full{
    width:98%;
    margin: 20px 1%;
    background: #212121;
    height: 40px;
}
.col-3{
    width: 33%;
    margin: 5px 1%;
    background: #3b5998;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    @media screen and (max-width: $tablet){
    width: 47.86%;  
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: $mobile){
    width: 98%; 
    }
}
.col-4{
    width: 26%;
    margin: 5px 1%;
    background: #ffff00;
    display: inline-block;
    //height: 40px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: -60px;
    min-height: 200px;
}
.col-7{
    width: 67%;
    margin: 5px 1%;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    //height: 40px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position: fixed` to your `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<body>
    <div class="columnas">
        <div class="full"></div>
        <div class="column1">
          <div class="col-7"><p>Text1</p></div>
          <div class="col-3"><p>Text3</p></div>
          <div class="col-3"><p>Text4</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4"><p>Text2</p></div>

    </div>
</body>
```

and the CSS:

```
 .columnas{
     overflow: hidden;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
 .column1 {
     flex: 0 0 70%;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     justify-content: space-between;
 }
 .full{
     flex:0 0 98%;
     margin: 20px 1%;
     background: #212121;
     height: 40px;
}
.col-3{
     flex:0 0 48%;
     margin: 5px 1%;
     background: #3b5998;
     height: 40px;
     @media screen and (max-width: $tablet){
        flex:0 0 47.86%;  /* ToDo */
     }
    @media screen and (max-width: $mobile){
       flex:0 0 98%; /* ToDo */
    }
}
.col-4{
    flex: 0 0 28%;
    margin: 5px 1%;
    background: #ffff00;
}
.col-7{
    flex:0 0 100%;
    margin: 5px 1%;
    background: red;
}
```